# Seeking an editing mode to ensure appropriate percolation of changes in function signatures

Tags: frames

Function calls come in chains. f1 calls f2; f2 calls f3; etc.

When the signature of one function along the chain changes during refactoring, the change often percolates up and down the chain.

With stock Emacs one can simply use C-x 3 (split-window-right), but that means frequently bringing down the split (C-x 1, C-x 0), and continuously hunting down for the path/to/file along the chain of files.

A user interface that would make it possible to swipe to left/right along the chain would be nice. Can you suggest a mode that would facilitate this kind of interaction?

[image: percolate frames right/left]

On a Mac, Desktops somewhat help, as in the picture below. Though this still requires a lot of synchronization between (Mac) Desktops, (Emacs) frames, and (Emacs) windows.

[image: mac desktops]

Ideally, C-x 3 would be within a special mode that is augmented with, say, `push-window-vertically-on-right`, followed by `shift-windows-vertically-left/right`. Does anything resembling this already exist?

Comment: The title of the question seems unrelated to the question itself. I suggest that you make this one a frame/window creation question and, if you like, ask a new one about refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to be able to quickly move from one frame to another.
There are various ways to do that.

- You can cycle among frames using command `other-frame`.
- If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use command `icicle-select-frame` (`C-x 5 o`) to cycle (e.g. using the arrow keys) among frames, in various orders, or to select frames by their names, with completion.
- If you use library [Frame Move](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameMove) then you can use the arrow keys to move among frames.

See the Emacs Wiki [Frames category page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryFrames) for more possibilities.

Others here will no doubt mention additional libraries/methods.